# Can httpRuntime targetFramework exceed compilation targetFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

My group has a ASP.Net MVC 5 web application that was compiled in 4.5.2 and which we do not have easy access to recompile to a later version. We are experiencing TLS issues with some remote calls which we were able to solve by simply altering our web.config to include `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />`. Are there any caveats to setting the httpRuntime targetFramework to a version that's later than the compilation target (given, of course, that the later version is installed on the web server)? In other words, are there any caveats for setting web.config as follows:
`<compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />`
`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />`

Answer (score 0):

Configuring  to a version later than  worked in our test environment, but out of concern for unintended consequences we ended up recompiling the app to a later version.